# Symfony2 : Empty $_FILES in controller using curl -F

Tags: symfony, curl

I'm trying to upload a file using curl in command line :

```
curl -v -X PATCH --form "file=@path/to/my/pngfile.png" http://127.0.0.1:8000/myresource/1
```

but in my controller when I try to dump, i have nothing :

```
var_dump($request->files);
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request:

`curl -v -X PATCH --form "file=@path/to/my/pngfile.png" http://127.0.0.1:8000/myresource/1`

You are using `-X` option. From manpage:

> Specifies a custom request method to use when communicating with the
>   HTTP server

So you should use here one from existing request methods: `GET/POST/PUT/DELETE`. **PATCH method doesn't exists.** Just change `PATCH` to `POST`, and press upvote :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking:

```
var_dump($request->request->all());
```

Comment: Empty too, here is the dump : <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
  <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre>